# When does a `QTreeView` emit the activated signal on Mac?

Tags: c++, qt

The following line of code works on Windows when you press **Return**, but not on Macs. Does anyone know why?

```
connect(qTreeView, SIGNAL(activated(const QModelIndex &)), this, SLOT(actJoin()));
```

When I look at the API it mentions

> This signal is emitted when the item specified by index is activated
>   by the user. **How to activate items depends on the platform**; e.g., by
>   single- or double-clicking the item, or by pressing the Return or
>   Enter key when the item is current.

Could there be another way to activate on Macs that I am missing?

Comment: If the API explictly states that activation is platform-dependent, alternatives are unlikely to be resolved.

Comment: This doesn't explain why RETURN would work any different on a Mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> should be the Mac version of activated as seen [here](https://github.com/Vitallium/qt5/blob/master/qtbase/src/widgets/itemviews/qabstractitemview.cpp#L2411)

```
#ifdef Q_WS_MAC
        if (event->key() == Qt::Key_O && event->modifiers() & Qt::ControlModifier && currentIndex().isValid()) {
            emit activated(currentIndex());
            break;
        }
```

Pressing Return on a Mac doesnt active it, it enters the edit mode.

Comment: Your users are unlikely to know about it, so it's best not to depend on this. This is not a standard shortcut on Macs. Or, rather, it is a standard shortcut to get to the `File->Open` menu. IMHO Qt's implementation here is useless, and you need to catch the relevant key press (Enter/Return) yourself by installing an event filter on the view.

Comment: After finding out the correct answer I also added a SIGNAL/SLOT so that it works the same across all operating systems.