# What key(s) emits the activated signal of a QListView item on MacOS?

Tags: macos, qt, key, shortcut, qlistview

I am developing a MacOS application with Qt. I have a QListView populated with a model. The problem is that the `activated(const QModelIndex &index)` is never emitted. I have already tried with `Enter`, `Return`, `Ctrl+O` and `Ctrl+down arrow` Nothing is happening. Just for the record, I have to mention that Enter causes the rename of the selected item's name.

I also have to say that when I run on windows, `activated(const QModelIndex &index)` is emitted with `Enter` key.

Any ideas on how can I catch this signal?

Comment: Have you tried single and double click?

Comment: Try spacebar :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When does a \`QTreeView\` emit the activated signal on Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31650780/when-does-a-qtreeview-emit-the-activated-signal-on-mac)